# 형이다마는 in this sentence is wrong, right?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I am learning the ㄴ/는다마는 structure, and i have a sentence as follows:

> 그 사람이 내 **형이다마는** 서로 얼굴을 안 본 지 오래되었어요. (That person is my brother, but we haven't seen each other for a long time)

As far as I understand this structure, ㄴ/는다마는 = ㄴ/는다고 하다 + 마는. Also from what I've learned about **indirect quotes**, "Noun + 이다" must be combined with 라고, not 다고. Therefore, the above sentence should have been rewritten as "그 사람이 내 **형이라마는** 서로 얼굴을 안 본 지 오래되었어요", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sentence is right.

- 형이다마는(O) 형이다지만(O or X)
- 형이라마는(X) 형이라지만(O)

**(O)형이다마는/형이다지만은** : 형이다("라" is also possible) 고 하지만은

**(O)형이라지만은** : 형이라고 하지만은

**(X)형이라마는** : We do not use such abbreviations.

Comment: Thank. Based on your answer, I can interpret it as  ㄴ/는다마는 = ㄴ/는다지만, and 마는 is a shortened form of 지만은, right?

Comment: 형이다마는, 형이다만, 형이다지만, 형이라지만, 형이라지만은 >> It's all pretty much the same.